# Gravity Forms - Setting Entry ID as hidden field of current form

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am tying to use this filter to update an existing entry:

- https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_entry_id_pre_save_lead/

However, in the documentation it says:

- This assumes that the entry ID to be updated has been submitted with the form from an input which as the input name "my_update_entry_id".

For my scenario it would be ideal if I could capture the Entry ID as part of the entry submission (in a hidden field).  Is there a way to do this?

Alternatively, I could dynamically assign an entry ID prior to it being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are updating an entry, I'm assuming it already exists. If it already exists, you should be able to use [dynamic population](https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/) to populate the existing entry ID into a Hidden field on the form. Then you can use the example from the gform_entry_id_pre_save_lead documentation to update the desired entry on submission.

Here's an existing snippet that does the same thing: https://gist.github.com/spivurno/32e914d67723f89717be2904ce6234c4

Comment: I just came back to answer my own question - I had found the same thing and have implemented something similar.  Thank you!

Comment: @Amanda I have the same issue , Can you help me and say your direction that how doing it?